# to get the latest 10 weeks of information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL query (SQL Server). I want to modify the below SQL query in a way that it only holds last **7 days** of information for Type 'Daily Score'
and holds **10 weeks** of information for 'Weekly Score'. Any inputs would be helpful.

```
SELECT 'Daily Score' AS Type, 
       product AS Product, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, productCreationDate, 23) AS productCreationDate 
FROM   ProductTable 
UNION 
SELECT 'Weekly Score' AS Type, 
       product AS Product, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(day, - Datepart(weekday, productCreationDate) + 1, productCreationDate 
       ), 23) 
       + '-' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(day, 7 - Datepart(weekday, productCreationDate), productCreationDate 
       ), 23) AS productCreationDate 
FROM   ProductTable;
```

Comment: You have no `WHERE` clause on your queries to filter the selects.  This will select all records from your `ProductTable` regardless of the associated date.

Comment: or TOP (10) with an ORDER BY clause

Comment: I don't think you should be using a `UNION` in your query or converting date information to `varchar` in your query as the two queries represent different sets of data (so they should be two batched queries) and dates should be converted to text in your application, not your query.

Comment: Agree, but i cannot modify the existing SQL any way except getting 7 days for Daily Score and 10 weeks information for Weekly score.Any inputs?

Comment: Do you have any example data?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dai that these possibly should be 2 distinct queries, but they can be combined into one to illustrate the data.

```
/* Last 7 days. */
SELECT [Type] = 'Daily Score'
    , product
    , productCreationDate /* I included the actual date in the query so you can see the one actually selected. */
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR, productCreationDate, 23) AS productCreationDateAsVarchar
FROM   ProductTable 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,productCreationDate,getDate()) <= 7

UNION ALL /* UNION ALL is significantly faster than UNION, so if you don't expect dupes, use UNION ALL. */

/* Last 10 weeks */
SELECT [Type] = 'Weekly Score'
       , product
       , productCreationDate
       , CONVERT(
               VARCHAR, 
               Dateadd(day, - Datepart(weekday, productCreationDate) + 1, productCreationDate )
       , 23) 
       + '-' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(day, 7 - Datepart(weekday, productCreationDate), productCreationDate 
       ), 23) AS productCreationDateAsVarchar
FROM   ProductTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(week,productCreationDate,getDate()) <=10
```

If I'm not mistaken, it looks like `productionCreationDate` in your original query is just a description of what block of date descriptions that `productionCreationDate` came from, so it's not really a date. It should probably be more descriptively named. And I'm not sure those values will actually give you useful information. I'd need example data to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using two separate queries instead of using a `UNION` because your two sub-queries conceptually represent different types of data (as in your current query the output `productCreationDate` column represents either a date or a week). Instead I'd use two different queries in the same batch (you can use a single `SqlCommand.ExecuteDataReader` for this, just call `NextResult` to move to the next result set).

Additionally, if you're working with weeks then you should use a tuple of the year and ISO week number and not simply the date rounded to the nearest sunday or monday (as this will give you different results depending on the locale/culture settings of the server!).

Finally, I generally recommend avoiding converting date/time values to text inside SQL because that's a view-level concern (as in "software that generates what the user sees on-screen", not a SQL `VIEW` btw).

Here's how I'd do it (with your requested date range filter):

```
-- Daily products:
SELECT
    product,
    productCreationDate
FROM
    ProductTable
WHERE
    productCreationDate >= DATEADD( day, -7, GETUTCDATE() ) 

-- Weekly products:
SELECT
    product,
    DATEPART( year, productCreationDate ) AS [year]
    DATEPART( iso_week, productCreationDate ) AS [isoWeek]
FROM
    ProductTable
WHERE
    productCreationDate >= DATEADD( week, -10, GETUTCDATE() )
```

Read like so:

```
using( SqlCommand cmd = yourConnection.CreateCommand() )
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ...";
    using( SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
    {
        // Read the Daily Products query results:
        while( rdr.Read() )
        {
            // ...
        }

        // Read the Weekly Products query results:
        rdr.NextResult();

        while( rdr.Read() )
        {
            // ...
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filters should be added to your queries so that you select the proper records in each of your queries.

```
SELECT 'Daily Score' AS Type
       product AS Product,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, productCreationDate, 23) AS productCreationDate
FROM   ProductTable
WHERE  productCreationDate >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETUTCDATE())
UNION
SELECT 'Weekly Score' AS Type
       product AS Product
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, productCreationDate, 23) AS productCreationDate
FROM   ProductTable
WHERE  productCreationDate >= DATEADD( week, -10, GETUTCDATE() )
```